# usging datastore-indexes.xml on development app engine server

Tags: java, google-app-engine

It seems that in development App Engine server datastore-indexes.xml doesn't work. Is it true?
Also, I created a datastore-indexes.xml file with autoGenerate="true" but it didn't generate me any indexes in datastore-indexes-auto.xml. Why?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<datastore-indexes autoGenerate="true">
    <datastore-index kind="UserData" ancestor="false">
        <property name="email" direction="asc" />
        <property name="email" direction="desc" />
        <property name="lastName" direction="asc" />
        <property name="lastName" direction="desc" />
    </datastore-index>
</datastore-indexes>
```

**UPDATED**

There is my entity:

```
@Entity
@Index
public class UserData implements PersistableObject {

    @Id
    Long id;

    String email;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    String middleName;
    String passwordHash;
    UserType userType;
}
```

There is my Dao:

```
public class UserDataDao {
    public List<UserData> getUsers(int startRow, int limit, String columnName, boolean ascending) {
        Query<UserData> query = ofy().load().type(UserData.class)
                .offset(startRow).limit(limit);
        if (columnName != null) {
            query.order((ascending ? "" : "-") + columnName);
        }
        return query.list();
    }

    public int usersCount() {
        return ofy().load().type(UserData.class).count();
    }

    public UserData find(Class<? extends UserData> aClass, Long userId) {
        return ofy().load().type(aClass).id(userId).now();
    }
}
```

Queries are being executed but indexes haven't created even if I leave only datastore-indexs tag.

Comment: Did you run queries in your devserver?

Comment: Yes, but I use Objectify.

Comment: That shouldn't change anything. If you have autogenerate set to true, the system should create all required indexes as you run queries...

Comment: But it does. Any other idea?

Comment: Alex that index doesn't make any sense, please elaborate on the queries you are running, my guess is neither needs additional indexes.

Comment: Jirungaray, I updated question about my queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Additional indexes are not being created because you are only querying on single attributes. Those indexes are automatically created when you @Index an attribute.

Additional indexes will be required on complex queries involving multiple attributes (both filtering and sorting).

**Tip: It's really a bad idea to index all fields on an entity, this will add several writes required to store every entity and that will raise your app costs FAST, consider only indexing the field you plan to filter,sort on**

Comment: Thank you for answer. But do you have any idea why sorting doesn't work? columnName is orderColumnName a column by which I want to sort a list.

Comment: are the fields you are trying to sort by indexed?

Comment: I think yes. They have Index annotation.

Comment: But are those fields indexed on the datastore? Remember that adding @Index will only affect new entities saved. If you saved some before adding it you'll have to re-save them for them to be included on the index

Comment: So you can filter by a column but not sort??

Comment: If you have an Entity with three properties neither of which have `@Index` annotation, but you have your datastore-indexes.xml file filled out using say, two of those properties, should your query still work? What about the reverse? If all your Entity properties have `@Index` annotation, but you have nothing in your datastore-indexes.xml file, will your query on two of those properties (for example, two `.filter()`'s)?

Comment: if you have nothing with @Index but have the proper composite indexes on xml you should be ok only querying on thos indexes (single prop filter queries will fail). On the other hand if you only have every property Indexed (no indexes on xml) queries filtering or ordering for a single property will work but  composite queries ( eg query for a, order by B ) will not